As a liberal poster, I am receiving heavy frivolous downvotes - and I am now blocked from asking questions
Like everywhere on the Stack Exchange, there is block downvoting. There seems to be a right-wing user block, that wants to silence me through downvotes.
If a right-wing group has veto-power over what gets posted - how fair is this forum? Why not change the name to "right wing politics", and people like me would know to stay away.

I expect the downvotes you're receiving are more to do with you describing people using phrases like "preternaturally annoying" and "hyper-nitpicking" and "I am not able to think I belong to the same species as the folk", all of which violate the site's Code of Conduct (especially that last one). I don't see anything in the question you posted those comments under to suggest that you are a liberal or that the users who objected to the original phrasing did so because they are right-wing.

This question is similar to: Does Politics Stack Exchange as a whole have a bias? If so, how can it possibly be quantified?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm referring to your comments on this question, which was indeed posted here on Politics.SE. I hardly see how taking a look at your questions when you're complaining about downvotes on them is "Gestapo tactics".

If you find it too difficult to take ownership of your actions and how they lesd to the consequences you experience and perceive as negative, and immediately seek to attack those who point out the connection or block them from being able to do so, this may not be the network for you.

Oddly enough, if you were to sed /right/left/ on the above (swap those terms around), you'd find precisely the same kind of complaints from right-leaning people claiming that this site is aaaawwwwfullly too liberal.  But I applaud your prescient prediction and grant you a -1 to get you on the way there.

(For reference, the comments I referred to above have now been deleted.)

FWIW, I upvoted that question  wrt F1Crazy's statements about your comments:  Treat people with respect and they will treat you respectfully in return.

Not sure why the edit was rolled back when it's a perfectly valid grammar edit. I can understand the argument against improving a question that's already at -7, but I see no reason for the improvement, once made, to be undone.

I get the same from various, obviously hostile groups or accounts.
A possible way to get out of this is to create some type of "gentleman's agreement": if we could agree that we vote only to the content and not for the "tribe".
However, I think, majority of the voters won't ever join such an agreement, or they will do it only in words. The stable point of this system is that everyone is voting to their own political view and against the others, and the site is going clearly into this direction.
Possibly there will be some "thaw" after the USA elections and the Ukrainian war, but not much and not long.
Note that initially even wikipedia started with the idea of that they explain all the relevant political views in sensitive topics... then it has just "evolved".
The root reason is that this site does not work and it should be closed. It is nowhere to wikipedia in size and possibilities, it will cause only harm.

'there will be some "thawt" after the USA elections'. Mebe.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever There is a stable state where the site is going, and that is a single-sided pro-Israel, pro-USA, liberal democrat line. Liberal democrat means the USA version of the word. Their view would be set up as the single objective reality, then they would moderate out everyone from a fake authority perspective. I think that is our direction. We will see, what will happen. I do not know, what to do. Now I think, there is also a strong group even between this "mainstream line" who do not want it, and that is a hope.
